# Iterative Permutations of Distribution

Tags: python, recursion, iteration, permutation, distribution

I'm trying to generate all possible combinations of a distribution of sorts.

For example, say you have 5 points to spend on 4 categories, but you can only spend a maximum of 2 points on any given category.
In this instance, all possible solutions would be as follows:

```
[0, 1, 2, 2]
[0, 2, 1, 2]
[0, 2, 2, 1]
[1, 0, 2, 2]
[1, 1, 1, 2]
[1, 1, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 0, 2]
[1, 2, 1, 1]
[1, 2, 2, 0]
[2, 0, 1, 2]
[2, 0, 2, 1]
[2, 1, 0, 2]
[2, 1, 1, 1]
[2, 1, 2, 0]
[2, 2, 0, 1]
[2, 2, 1, 0]
```

I have successfully been able to make a recursive function that accomplishes this, but for larger numbers of categories it takes extremely long to generate. I have attempted making an iterative function instead in hopes of speeding it up, but I can't seem to get it to account for the category maximums.

Here is my recursive function (count = points, dist = zero-filled array w/ same size as max_allo)

```
def distribute_recursive(count, max_allo, dist, depth=0):
    for ration in range(max(count - sum(max_allo[depth + 1:]), 0), min(count, max_allo[depth]) + 1):
        dist[depth] = ration
        count -= ration
        if depth + 1 < len(dist):
            distribute_recursive(count, max_allo, dist, depth + 1)
        else:
            print(dist)
        count += ration
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Do you want us to write code that gives the same output but use iteration rather than recursion?

Comment: Perhaps itertools permutations: https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**recursion isn't slow**

Recursion isn't what's making it slow; consider a better algorithm

```
def dist (count, limit, points, acc = []):
  if count is 0:
    if sum (acc) is points:
      yield acc
  else:
    for x in range (limit + 1):
      yield from dist (count - 1, limit, points, acc + [x])
```

You can collect the generated results in a list

```
print (list (dist (count = 4, limit = 2, points = 5)))
```

**pruning invalid combinations**

Above, we use a fixed range of `limit + 1`, but watch what happens if we're generating a combination with a (eg) `limit = 2` and `points = 5` ...

```
[ 2, ... ]    # 3 points remaining
[ 2, 2, ... ] # 1 point remaining
```

At this point, using a fixed range of `limit + 1` (`[ 0, 1, 2 ]`) is silly because we know we only have 1 point remaining to spend. The only remaining options here are `0` or `1`...

```
[ 2, 2, 1 ... ] # 0 points remaining
```

Above we know we can use an empty range of `[ 0 ]` because there's no points left to spend. This will prevent us from attempting to validate combinations like

```
[ 2, 2, 2, ... ] # -1 points remaining
[ 2, 2, 2, 0, ... ] # -1 points remaining
[ 2, 2, 2, 1, ... ] # -2 points remaining
[ 2, 2, 2, 2, ... ] # -3 points remaining
```

If `count` was significantly large, this could rule out a *huge* amount of invalid combinations

```
[ 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, ... ] # -15 points remaining
```

To implement this optimization, we could add yet another parameter to our `dist` function, but at 5 parameters, it would start to look messy. Instead we introduce an auxiliary function to control the `loop`. Adding our optimization, we trade the fixed range for a *dynamic* range of `min (limit, remaining) + 1`. And finally, since we know how many points have been allocated, we no longer need to test the `sum` of each combination; yet another expensive operation removed from our algorithm

```
# revision: prune invalid combinations
def dist (count, limit, points):
  def loop (count, remaining, acc):
    if count is 0:
      if remaining is 0:
        yield acc
    else:
      for x in range (min (limit, remaining) + 1):
        yield from loop (count - 1, remaining - x, acc + [x])
  yield from loop (count, points, [])
```

**benchmarks**

In the benchmarks below, the first version of our program is renamed to `dist1` and the faster program using a dynamic range `dist2`. We setup three tests, `small`, `medium`, and `large`

```
def small (prg):
  return list (prg (count = 4, limit = 2, points = 5))

def medium (prg):
  return list (prg (count = 8, limit = 3, points = 7))

def large (prg):
  return list (prg (count = 16, limit = 5, points = 10))
```

And now we run the tests, passing each program as an argument. Note for the `large` test, only 1 pass is done as `dist1` takes awhile to generate the result

```
print (timeit ('small (dist1)', number = 10000, globals = globals ()))
print (timeit ('small (dist2)', number = 10000, globals = globals ()))

print (timeit ('medium (dist1)', number = 100, globals = globals ()))
print (timeit ('medium (dist2)', number = 100, globals = globals ()))

print (timeit ('large (dist1)', number = 1, globals = globals ()))
print (timeit ('large (dist2)', number = 1, globals = globals ()))
```

The results for the `small` test show that pruning invalid combinations doesn't make much of a difference. However in the `medium` and `large` cases, the difference is dramatic. Our old program takes over 30 minutes for the large set, but just over 1 second using the new program!

```
dist1 small      0.8512216459494084
dist2 small      0.8610155049245805   (0.98x speed-up)

dist1 medium     6.142372329952195
dist2 medium     0.9355670949444175   (6.57x speed-up)

dist1 large   1933.0877765258774
dist2 large      1.4107366011012346   (1370.26x speed-up)
```

For frame of reference, the size of each result is printed below

```
print (len (small (dist2)))   # 16      (this is the example in your question)
print (len (medium (dist2)))  # 2472
print (len (large (dist2)))   # 336336
```

**checking our understanding**

In the `large` benchmark with `count = 12` and `limit = 5`, using our unoptimized program we were iterating through 5<sup>12</sup>, or 244,140,625 *possible* combinations. Using our optimized program, we skip all invalid combinations resulting in 336,336 valid answers. By analyzing combination count alone, we see a staggering 99.86% of *possible* combinations are invalid. If analysis of each combination costs an equal amount of time, we can expect our optimized program to perform at a minimum of 725.88x better, due to invalid combination pruning.

In the `large` benchmark, measured at 1370.26x faster, the optimized program meets our expectations and even goes beyond. The additional speed-up is likely owed to the fact we eliminated the call to `sum`

**huuuuge**

To show this technique works for extremely large data sets, consider the `huge` benchmark. Our program finds 17,321,844 valid combinations amongst 7<sup>16</sup>, or 33,232,930,569,601 possibilities.

In this test, our optimized program prunes 99.99479% of the invalid combinations. Correlating these numbers to the previous data set, we estimate the optimized program runs 1,918,556.16x faster than the unoptimized version.

The theoretical running time of this benchmark using the unoptimized program is **117.60 years**. The optimized program finds the answer in just over 1 minute.

```
def huge (prg):
  return list (prg (count = 16, limit = 7, points = 12))

print (timeit ('huge (dist2)', number = 1, globals = globals ()))
# 68.06868170504458

print (len (huge (dist2)))
# 17321844
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a generator function for the recursion, while applying additional logic to cut down on the number of recursive calls needed:

```
def listings(_cat, points, _max, current = []):
   if len(current) == _cat:
      yield current
   else:
      for i in range(_max+1):
        if sum(current+[i]) <= points:
          if sum(current+[i]) == points or len(current+[i]) < _cat:
             yield from listings(_cat, points, _max, current+[i])


print(list(listings(4, 5, 2)))
```

Output:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 2], [0, 2, 1, 2], [0, 2, 2, 1], [1, 0, 2, 2], [1, 1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2, 1], [1, 2, 0, 2], [1, 2, 1, 1], [1, 2, 2, 0], [2, 0, 1, 2], [2, 0, 2, 1], [2, 1, 0, 2], [2, 1, 1, 1], [2, 1, 2, 0], [2, 2, 0, 1], [2, 2, 1, 0]]
```

While it is unclear at around what category size your solution drastically slows down, this solution will run under one second for category sizes up to `24`, searching for a total of five points with a maximum slot value of two. Note that for large point and slot values, the number of possible category sizes computed under a second increases:

```
import time

def timeit(f):
   def wrapper(*args):
     c = time.time()
     _ = f(*args)
     return time.time() - c
   return wrapper

@timeit
def wrap_calls(category_size:int) -> float:
  _ = list(listings(category_size, 5, 2))

benchmark = 0
category_size = 1
while benchmark < 1:
   benchmark = wrap_calls(category_size)
   category_size += 1

print(category_size)
```

Output:

```
24
```

Comment: dangit, i just finished writing the same answer before reading yours. No joke, almost [completely identical](https://repl.it/repls/VillainousSneakyKeyboardmacro) :D

Comment: @user633183 I really like your solution, as it is even cleaner than mine. I encourage you to undelete it :)

Comment: Thanks, I made the answer visible again. Though I just had an idea which might speed it up even more. I'll see if it works...

Comment: Ajax1234, the tweak seems to have had a big impact. I created a large test case and ended up walking away because it took my first program so long to complete it. I shared the results in an update to my answer :D